# Case insensitive isMember in loop - JPA criteria api

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I created the following predicate that matches a given set of string e.g. "a,b,c" against an column containing an `@ElementCollection Set<String>`. 
I want all entries that contain "a" or "b" or "c". E.g. all these entries/set match:

- `a` //because of a
- `b,d` //because of b
- `c,f,g` //because of c

I have a predicate that is working - i only need to make it case insensitive (don't want to change the data base):

```
private Predicate matchStringSet(Set<String> set, SetAttribute<DeliveryModeEntity, String> attribute,
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<DeliveryModeEntity> deliveryMode) {
        List<Predicate> matchEach = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : set) {
            matchEach.add(criteriaBuilder.isMember(string.toLowerCase(), deliveryMode.get(attribute)));

        }
        return criteriaBuilder.or(matchEach.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

}
```

How to make `deliveryMode.get(attribute)` use lower case or how to make this case insensitive. 
I tried to use a join as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10225074/447426
but this is not working within a for loop - it will create a join per string in set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar entity, `Widget`, having tags:

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "tag")
private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

With what you have, to find all widgets having given tags use:

```
private Predicate matchTags(List<String> tags, Root<Widget> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
  List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

  for (String tag : tags) {
    predicates.add(cb.isMember(tag, root.get(Widget_.tags)));
  }
  return PredicateReducer.OR.reduce(cb, predicates); // cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

To find all Widgets having given tags in a case-insensitive way, first join the tags and then perform a like search:

```
private Predicate matchTagsCaseInsensitive(List<String> tags, Root<Widget> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
  List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
  Join<Widget, String> joinedTag = root.join(Widget_.tags);

  for (String tag : tags) {
    predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(joinedTag), tag.toLowerCase()));
  }
  return PredicateReducer.OR.reduce(cb, predicates); // cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

**Edit: Adding PredicateReducer**

I find myself `AND`-ing or `OR`-ing predicates often, so wrapped those operations into an enum:

```
public enum PredicateReducer {
  AND {
    @Override
    public Predicate reduce(CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Predicate> predicates) {
      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
  },
  OR {
    @Override
    public Predicate reduce(CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Predicate> predicates) {
      return cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
  };

  public abstract Predicate reduce(CriteriaBuilder cb, List<Predicate> predicates);

  public Predicate reduce(CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate... predicates) {
    return reduce(cb, Arrays.asList(predicates));
  }
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity: what is PredicateReducer?

Comment: Edited to include `PredicateReducer` enum.  Hope it's useful!